# Removing a row from a Range of Rows generated by Unions in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, union

This seems like it should be simple to execute, but for the life of me I cannot find the proper command or trick.

In my macro, I systematically generate a Range of Rows using Union between the Range and the new row in a loop:

```
Set DesiredRange = Union(DesiredRange, ActiveSheet.Cells(Val(ParsedText(Count)), 1).EntireRow)
```

However, in order for this union to work, I must first Set the `DesiredRange` equal to some range so that the Union does not error out.

The trouble I am having is that there are certain row numbers that I need to disclude, but the rows are chosen from a userform textbox that allows the user to input whatever they wish (I've coded in error control so that the values passed are valid), so they can hypothetically make the first value (and thus the one I am using to initialize the range) a discluded row.

I am hoping someone here can have a solution that allows me to complete all the operations and then remove this first added row from the range if it is within the discluded category (rows 1 through 7).  If not, I think I may have a work around (but part of me is asking this question more for education than solving the problem)

Thanks!

Comment: Immediately after posting this, I found a work around using a small for loop and another counter, but I'm still hoping someone can enlighten me as to any methods that might do what I had originally asked for

Comment: The key is in the `If rngTarget Is Nothing Then` section in Robin's answer - you just don't assign a random range to start with!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'd like a function like `Range.Except` to complement `Range.Intersect` and `Range.Union` but AFAIK no such function is built in to VBA and you'd have to code it yourself. Something like the following will perform what you want and automatically excluded unwanted rows from the `Union`. The variable `strRowsToExclude` would probably be passed to the method from your form:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Dim strRowsToExclude As String
    Dim varRowsToExclude As Variant
    Dim intCounter1 As Integer
    Dim intCounter2 As Integer
    Dim blnDoNotAdd  As Boolean

    Set rngTarget = Nothing
    strRowsToExclude = "1,4,45,87,88,99"
    varRowsToExclude = Split(strRowsToExclude, ",")

    For intCounter1 = 1 To 100
        blnDoNotAdd = False
        For intCounter2 = 0 To UBound(varRowsToExclude)
            If intCounter1 = Val(varRowsToExclude(intCounter2)) Then
                blnDoNotAdd = True
            End If
        Next intCounter2
        If blnDoNotAdd = False Then
            If rngTarget Is Nothing Then
                Set rngTarget = Sheet1.Cells(intCounter1, 1).EntireRow
            Else
                Set rngTarget = Union(rngTarget, Sheet1.Cells(intCounter1, 1).EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next intCounter1

    rngTarget.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I guess I should have included the full code for reference.  I already had all the exclusions working and only needed to account for the first row that was added.  Built a cheeky workaround using a short loop to run through the first values until a suitable first value was found. I was more just curious if there were a simpler solution for removing the section from the range after it had been added.  I can't find any documentation for the 'Range.Except' method you are referencing though

Comment: Still marking your answer correct as it did solve the problem in a fairly concise way, even if i didn't need it answered.  I should note that the upper would better be set to the number of elements in the given input string in case of very large datasets

Comment: RGA - thanks. There is no `Range.Except` method - but it would be very useful in this circumstance and many others. They call it `Subtract` in this link: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2007/08/17/two-new-range-functions-union-and-subtract/

Comment: I also found that in my research but was hoping I wouldn't have to write a sub to remove the row, particularly since it could be time intensive for large ranges.

Answer (score 0):

you could do like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim desiredRng As Range, forbiddenRows As Range, cell As Range
    Dim rowsStrng As String
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Set forbiddenRows = .Range("1:1, 3:5, 7:7, 9:11") '<~~ set forbidden rows, you can use multiple rows sintax            
        For i = 1 To 10 '<~~ this is your "Union" loop, 
            ' do stuff to get to following line
            Set cell = .Cells(Val(ParsedText(Count)), 1)
            If Intersect(cell, forbiddenRows) Is Nothing Then rowsStrng = rowsStrng & cell.Row & ":" & cell.Row & "," '<~~ add row index only if not forbidden
        Next i
        If rowsStrng <> "" Then Set desiredRng = .Range(Left(rowsStrng, Len(rowsStrng) - 1))
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @RGA did you try this? it should be both shorter (to code and thus to maintain!) and faster (to execute, since it avoids a loop through forbidden rows index list for every row)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Rory's comment:

```
Dim DesiredRange As Range, rng As Range

'...in your loop
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(Val(ParsedText(Count)), 1).EntireRow
If DesiredRange Is Nothing Then
    Set DesiredRange = rng
Else
    Set DesiredRange = Application.Union(DesiredRange, rng)
End If
```